# Django get_or_create not getting data back

Tags: django, django-views, bootstrap-modal

i have created a FBV for Modal form (popup) i want to have the same view to handle both create and update, the reason i am using FBV is that am assigning the foreign key through queries rather that passing the id through the URL. Please note the JS script am using to call the Modal and render the form in it.

````
**Models.py:**

class Startup ( models.Model ) :
    author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

class Startup_About ( models.Model ) :
    str_about = models.OneToOneField ( Startup , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    about = models.TextField ( 'About Startup' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
    problem = models.TextField ( 'Problem/Opportunity' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
    business_model = models.TextField ( 'Business Monitization Model' , max_length = 2000 , null = False ,blank = False )
    offer = models.TextField ( 'Offer to Investors' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )

    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.str_about)

**forms.py:**

class startupform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup
        fields = ('startup_name',)
        widgets = {
            'startup_name': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        super ( ).clean ( )
        startup_name = self.cleaned_data.get ( 'startup_name' )
        startup_qs = Startup.objects.filter ( startup_name = startup_name )
        if startup_qs.exists ( ):
            raise forms.ValidationError ( 'This Startup Already Exist!' )

class startupaboutform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup_About
        fields = ('about','problem','business_model','offer',)
        widgets = {
            'about' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
            'problem' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
            'business_model' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
            'offer' : forms.Textarea ( attrs = { 'class' : 'form-control' } ) ,
        }

**Views.py:**

@login_required
@str_required
def create_startupform(request):
    q = Startup.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    if q.exists():
        return redirect ( 'appwizard')
    else:
        form = startupform ( request.POST or None )
        if form.is_valid ( ) :
            instance = form.save (commit = False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect ( 'appwizard', pk = instance.pk )
        else:
            form = startupform()
        return render ( request , 'str_name.html' , { 'form' : form } )

decorators = [str_required, login_required]

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(str_required, name='dispatch')
class aboutview(FormView):
    template_name = 'create_about.html'
    form_class = startupaboutform

@login_required
@str_required
def create_startupaboutform(request) :
    q = Startup.objects.filter ( author = request.user )[0]
    R = get_object_or_404(Startup, startup_name=q)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = startupaboutform ( request.POST )
        stup = Startup_About.objects.get_or_create(str_about=R )[0]
        if form.is_valid ( ) :
            instance = form.save ( commit = False )
            instance.str_about = R
            instance.save ( )
            return redirect('/appwizard/')
        else :
            form = startupaboutform ()
        return render ( request , 'create_about.html' , { 'form' : form } )

**urls.py:**

urlpatterns = [

    path ( 'appwizard/' , views.applicationwizard , name = 'appwizard' ) ,
    path('create_startupaboutform/', views.create_startupaboutform, name='create_startupaboutform'),
    path ( 'aboutview/' , views.aboutview.as_view() , name = 'aboutview' ) ,

]

**Template - appwizard:**

{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

</head>
<body>


<a href="#"  id="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</a>


{% include "create_about.html" %}


<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#btn").on("click", function(){
                 $("#form").load("{% url 'aboutview' %}", function(){
                 $("#about").modal("show");
             });
             });
     });
</script>

</body>
</html>

**Template - creaye_about - form in a Modal:**

<form id="form" method="post" action="{% url 'create_startupaboutform' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal fade" id="about" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{form}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your `clean` method should return the cleaned data, so:

```
class startupform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup
        fields = ('startup_name',)
        widgets = {
            'startup_name': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        startup_name = cleaned_data.get('startup_name')
        startup_qs = Startup.objects.filter(startup_name=startup_name)
        if startup_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This Startup Already Exist!')
        return cleaned_data
```

That being said, you might want to make `startup_name` *unique* by setting the [**`unique=True`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique), then Django will validate that itself, and the constraint will (likely) be enforced at the database level as well:

```
class Startup(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    startup_name = models.CharField('Startup Name', max_length=32, unique=True)
```

Comment: thanks for input but my issue is with the second view create_startupaboutform, however, if i user Unique does that mean there is no need for the form validation to be done?

Comment: thanks for input but my issue is with the second view create_startupaboutform,

Comment: should be using Update_or_create rather than Get_or_create function

Comment: to simplify the question how can i restrict the user that when he create the model objects he can only update and not allowed to access the create view again.